# XML deserialization on android using Simple API

Tags: android

Can anyone give me a link of a tutorial(specially a simple project which deserialize a XML on android using [Simple API](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/). I need this badly.

Answer (score 5):

Simple API works fine on Android, and it does not require any configuration. Just:

- Place the Simple jar in the libs directory
- Configure your Build Path to include that jar
- Enjoy. You can take a look at the samples if you haven't yet: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php

Comment: Finally, an XML deserializer that works on Android 2.3.3 and is really simple to use!

Comment: I have integrated this lib and it's working like a charm for me but having a problem in skipping unwanted Xml tags, do you know how to skip the tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740934/how-to-ignore-unused-xml-elements-while-deserializing-a-document