# How to ignore unused XML elements while deserializing a document?

Tags: java, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I'm using SimpleXml to (de)serialize POJOs. Now, I have a big XML which has some elements which are not needed. For instance, with this XML:

```
<Root>
   <Element>Used</Element>
   <Another>Not used</Another>
<Root>
```

I want to create a POJO which looks like:

```
@Root
class Root{
    @Element
    private String element;
}
```

Problem is that I'm getting this Exception:

```
simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Another' does not have a
match in class blah.blah.Blah at line 1
```

So... how should I configure the POJO so that I can parse the XML correctly?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Set `strict` to false within the Root annotation to ignore any XML elements or attributes that do not appear in the class.

```
@Root(strict=false)
```

**Alternatively**, set  `strict` to false when you read the xml in the [serialiser](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Serializer.html#read(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.File,%20boolean)):

```
Root root = serializer.read(Root.class, source, false);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can add (required=false) to a single element

```
@Element(required=false)
private int statusCode;
```

if you have more elements use

```
 @Root(strict=false)
```