# Xml deserialization ValueRequiredException

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, simple-framework

i'm deserializing a Xml file which is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserLists>
    <user>
      <username>Salesman1</username>
      <password>123</password>
      <salesmanId>4</salesmanId>
    </user>
  </UserLists>
</UserList>
```

with this line that throws me the Exception :

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=user, inline=true, name=, required=true, type=void) on field 'user' public java.util.List azdad.pos.android.UserList.user for class azdad.pos.android.UserList at line 2
```

my entity class is :

```
import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Path;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="UserList",strict=false)

public class UserList{


     @ElementList(entry="user", inline=true)
     public List<UserInfo> user;

     public List<UserInfo> getUsrs(){
         return user;
     }
}
```

I've used

> strict

to ignore the Tag According to this link :

[How to ignore unused XML elements while deserializing a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740934/how-to-ignore-unused-xml-elements-while-deserializing-a-document)

but it doesn't work , does anybody know how can i ignore  tag for deserializng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to ignore is `<UserLists>` tag right ?
Your problem comes from using `inline` attribute (see [Simple XML inlining](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#scatter)), you need rather to use :

```
@Root(name="UserList")
public class UserList{


    @ElementList(name="UserLists", entry="user")
    public List<UserInfo> user;

    public List<UserInfo> getUsers(){
        return user;
    }
}
```

The `strict` attribute shouldn't be needed then.

Note : I corrected a syntax error in `getUsers()`: as Simple uses reflection, this might be important.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer,finally i've solved that with creating an in between class for <UserLists>, i will try your solution later and again i appreciate your help